# mysql query prints data of different rows in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, popsql

I am using MySQL version 8.0 and popSQL as the editor.

Table:

```
create table account (no int, salary int);


insert into account values
(901,25000),
(902,30000),
(903,21000),
(904,40000),
(905,27000);
```

Now, I want no and salary of person with highest salary.
Highest salary is 40000 and corresponding no is 904.
But, this query is giving me different output.

```
-- no and salary of max salary
select no, max(salary)
from account ;
```

The output is: 
no  max(salary)
901 40000

It is printing the first no and the max salary.
i.e. data of different rows are shown in a same row.
How to fix this???

Same type of problem for my next query.

```
-- no and salary of second highest salary.
select no, max(salary)
from account
where salary not in
(select max(salary) from account);
```

The output is:
no  max(salary)
901 30000

Whereas expected is 902,30000.

I searched through the stack overflow for issue where data of different rows are shown in one but didn't get any help.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What if there is more than one such person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Highest Salary

```
select no, salary from (
    select no, salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by salary order by salary desc) as rn
    from account
) as a
where rn = 1 limit 1
```

> For Second highest salary

```
select no, salary from (
    select no, salary, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by salary order by salary desc) as rn
    from account
) as a
where rn = 2 limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want no and salary of person with highest salary

You don't need aggregation for this. You can just order by and limit:

```
select no, salary
from account
order by salary desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I did it with limit in the first place. I wanted to do this with other method. And this method is bugging me because my expected output is different from actual output. So I want to know how to alter this method to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL version 5.7.5 and older is notorious for accepting malformed SQL queries.

In *standard SQL* when there's no `GROUP BY` clause, all columns must be aggregated or not. You, however, chose to aggregate one, but not the other. This is illegal in SQL and can lead to non-deterministic results. But... MySQL accepts it.

Use it at your own risk.

**Note**: This bad behavior can be enabled in future versions of MySQL for compatibility reasons. I would encourage you not to do such a thing.

Comment: This is controlled by `sql_mode` option `only_full_group_by`. However sometimes it's really necessary to add non-grouped fields into result, but that must be done carefully and wisely.